# Function not found in wordpress PHP file

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to create a plugin that will allow for custom single post templates based on category. The code isn't running because I get this error:

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'my_single_template' not found or invalid function name

This is the relevant code:

```
function my_single_template($single) {
    global $wp_query, $post; 

/** * Checks for single template by category * Check by category slug and ID */
foreach((array)get_the_category() as $cat) :  
    if(file_exists(SINGLE_PATH . 'single-' . $cat->slug . '.php'))
        $single = SINGLE_PATH . 'single-' . $cat->slug . '.php'; 
    
    elseif(file_exists(SINGLE_PATH . 'single-' . $cat->term_id . '.php'))
         $single = SINGLE_PATH . 'single-' . $cat->term_id . '.php'; 
    
    endforeach;
    
    return $single;
}

/** * Filter the single_template with our custom function */ 
add_filter('single_template', 'my_single_template');

?>
```

I'm not understanding, as the add_filter is called after the function is declared.. so it should be working?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please refer this answer here [Error: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108860/error-call-user-func-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-a-valid-callback)

Comment: @Bhautik so I need to do `add_filter('single_template', array($single, 'my_single_template'));` ?